# Given any two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ can we always find $c \neq 0$ and $Y \neq 0$ such that $AY = cBY$ is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given any two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ can we always find a scalar $c \neq 0$ and $n \times 1$ vector $Y \neq 0$ such that $AY = cBY$ is true ?

Answer (score 2):

No. Take, for instance, the orthogonal projections onto the $x$-axis and $y$-axis. In other words, let $A=\left [\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $B=\left [\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

For a nonsingular example, let $A$ be the identity and $B$ be a rotation by, for instance, $90^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

$AY=cBY$ if and only if $(A-cB)Y=0$. So, you are essentially asking whether there always exists a scalar $c$ such that $A-cB$ is singular.

When $B$ is nonsingular and the underlying field is algebraically closed, the answer is yes, because $\det(A-cB)=\det(AB^{-1}-cI)\det(B)$ is zero whenever $c$ is an eigenvalue of $AB^{-1}$.

However, the answer to your question is no in general. In particular, when $B=0$ and $A$ is nonsingular, the $c$ and $Y$ you require obviously do not exist.